# Factorize $3m^4-6m^3+14m^2-6m+11$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have this expression:
$3m^4-6m^3+14m^2-6m+11=0$ and I want to factorize it in $(m^2+1)(3m^2-6m+11)$.
How can I do it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please clarify: are you looking to show that that is the factorization, or are you asking how you would have discovered that factorization if you hadn't already known about it?

Answer (score 9):

**Hint** $\ $ Because the leading and constants coefficients are *primes*, the possible factors are highly constrainted, so we can quickly find quadratic factors by undetermined coefficients. First, notice $\rm\:mod\ 3\!:\ -f \equiv x^2+1,\:$ so we check for a factor of form $\rm\: x^2\! +\, 3a\, x + 1.\:$ Its cofactor must have leading coefficient $3$ and constant coefficient $11$, i.e.

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} (x^2+3a\,x+1)(3\,x^2\!+b\,x+11) &\,=\:&\rm 3\,x^4 + (b\!+\!9a)\, x^3 + (14\!+\!3ab)\, x^2 + (b\!+\!33a)\,x + 11 \\
&=&\rm 3\, x^2 - 6\, x^3 + 14\, x^2 - 6\,x + 11\end{eqnarray}$$

Comparing $\rm\:x^2$ terms, $\rm\:14=14\!+\!3ab\Rightarrow ab=0\:$ so $\rm\,a=0\,$ or $\rm\,b=0.\:$ If $\rm\:b=0\:$ then comparing $\rm\,x^3$ terms, $\rm\:9a=-6,\,$ contra $\rm\:a\in \Bbb Z.\:$ Thus $\rm\:a=0.\:$ Comparing $\rm\,x^3$ terms, $\rm\:b = -6,\:$ which works.

Comment: Nice answer. I like your unique formatting style!

Answer (score 7):

$3m^4-6m^3+14m^2-6m+11$

$=3m^4-6m^3+11m^2+3m^2-6m+11$

$=m^2(3m^2-6m+11)+(3m^2-6m+11)$

$=(m^2+1)(3m^2-6m+11)$

Comment: But this appears to pull the solution out of a hat. You should say why you tried that particular factorization. See my answer for one such explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f$ be the polynomial. If you know about complex numbers, you can compute $f(i) = 0$, showing you that $f$ is divisible by $(m - i)$. Since the coefficients are real, also $-i$ is a root, and so $f$ is divisible by $(m + i)$, too. Therefore $f$ is divisible by $(m - i)(m + i) = m^2 + 1$. Polynomial long division now gives you the factorization.

EDIT: How do you see $f(i) = 0$? If $f = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i X^i$ with real coefficients $a_i$, this is quite easy to check: $f(i) = 0$ if and only if the two alternating sums
$$a_0 - a_2 + a_4 - a_6 \pm \ldots\quad\text{and}\quad a_1 - a_3 + a_5 - a_7 \pm \ldots$$
both equal zero.
In this example, $11-14 + 3 = 0$ and $(-6)-(-6) = 0$, so $f(i) = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure how seeing $f(i) = 0$ is any easier than seeing that $(m^2+1)$ is a factor outright.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon: Well, since the coefficients of $f$ are real, both conditions are equivalent. With this knowledge, you see $f(i) = 0$ if and only if you see $m^2 + 1 \mid f$.

Comment: ... And the point is that many students would arguably *not* see either!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 For a polynomial $f = a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2 + \ldots$ with real coefficients, the check for $f(i) = 0$ is routine and almost as easy as $f(1) = 0$ or $f(-1) = 0$: $f(i) = 0$ means that the two alternating sums $a_0 - a_2 + a_4 - a_6 \pm\ldots$ and $a_1 - a_3 + a_5 - a_7 \pm\ldots$ both equal zero. In this case, $3 - 14 + 11 = 0$ and $-6 -(-6) = 0$.

Comment: I appreciate the bit about alternating sums. Always something new to learn! What if the polynomial were the product of two irreducible trinomials (with nonzero linear coefficients)?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: Thank you. Seems that the trick with the alternating sums is not quite well-known; I will include it in the anser. On yor question: The strategy for factoring polynomials is typically trying all your tools, from the easier to the more time-consuming ones. Recovering the factors from the product of two random irreducible cubic polynomials is quite hard. In general, one has to apply a technique like in the answer of MathGems, I guess. However, for the polynomial in this question, noticing $f(i) = 0$ is faster.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon For the case you didn't know the method with the alternating sums: I've added an explanation how to easliy see $f(i) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You already factorized the  $3m^4 −6m^3 +14m^2 −6m+11$ with $(m^2 +1)(3m^2 −6m+11)$.
First factor equals to $(m^2 +1)$ and second $(3m^2 −6m+11)$.
$(m^2 +1)(3m^2 −6m+11) = 3m^4-6m^3+11m^2+3m^2-6m+11 = 3m^4-6m^3+14m^2+11$

Note:
But if you need solve $3m^4 −6m^3 +14m^2 −6m+11 = 0$ using factorization $(m^2 +1)(3m^2 −6m+11)$ it's a little different problem.
 $(m^2 +1)(3m^2 −6m+11) = 0$ is true if 1.:$m^2 +1 = 0$ or 2.:$3m^2 −6m+11=0$.
1. $m^2 +1 = 0$ => $m_{1,2} = \pm\sqrt{-1} = \pm{i}$
2. $3m^2 −6m+11=0$ => $m_{3,4} = 1\pm{2}i\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

Here are four solutions:
1. $m = i$ : $3i^4-6i^3+14i^2-6i+11 = 3+6i+14-6i+11 = 0$
2. $m = -i$ : $3(-i)^4-6(-i)^3+14(-i)^2-6(-i)+11$
$ = 3(-1)^4i^4-6(-1)^3i^3+14(-1)^2i^2-6(-i)+13 = 3 -6i-14+6i+13 = 0$
3. $m = 1+{2}i\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$: substitute to equation as in 1. or 2.
4. $m = 1-{2}i\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$: substitute to equation as in 1. or 2.